# Calculo Consumo de água em Java,usando IDE Eclipse

Tags: java

Estou com dificuldades para escrever esse exercício na Linguagem Java, usando a IDE Eclipse:

> A diretora de uma escola estadual da cidade de São Paulo está apavorada com o consumo absurdo de água que vem ocorrendo mensalmente. Com o intuito de levantar informações que a levem a tomar decisões de contenção de despesas, ela te contratou para desenvolver um programa que realize a leitura do consumo de água no mês, em m3, e informe o valor da conta.
>   Dados: considere que cada  m3 vale R$ 2,00; além disso são acrescentados R$ 20,00 de esgoto e 15% de impostos.

Eu não estou conseguindo fazer com que o programa realize os cálculos.
No meu caso primeiro devo calcular o imposto, para depois "jogar" ele na fórmula para calcular o valor do consumo de água.

MEU CÒDIGO

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Agua {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        int consumo;
        int valore;
        int imposto;

                System.out.println("Informar o valor do consumo");

                Scanner Leio = new Scanner(System.in);
                consumo = Leio.nextInt();

                imposto = (2 * consumo + 20) * 15/100;
                System.out.println("O imposto é ");


                System.out.println("Informe o valor do imposto");
                valore = (2 * consumo + 20) + imposto;

                System.out.println("O Valor é de: R$ ");
                Leio.close();

            }

}
```

Estou com dificuldades nesse exercício, pois depois que eu digito o valor do consumo não ocorre nada!

Abaixo segue as fórmulas pelo VisualG onde os caculos ocorrem sem problemas (professor doido quer o Portugol/Visualg e o Java)!

[image: VISUALG]

Minha segunda imagem é a tela no Eclipse após eu informar o valor do "consumo"

[image: JAVA]

Comment: No caso não aparece nada na tela, por que você não está imprimindo as variáveis. Seu System.out.println está apenas imprimindo o texto. Tente colocar `System.out.println("O imposto é " + imposto);` e `System.out.println(O valor é de R$: " + valore);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha o java é bem mais maleável que o portugol, você pode fazer isso, se não entender qualquer coisa pode me perguntar. Ok?

```
public class Agua {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Informar o valor do consumo");
        Scanner Leio = new Scanner(System.in);
        int consumo = Leio.nextInt();
        int imposto = (2 * consumo + 20) * 15 / 100;
        System.out.println("O imposto é " + imposto);
        System.out.println("Informe o valor do imposto");
        int valore = (2 * consumo + 20) + imposto;
        System.out.println("O Valor é de: R$ " + valore);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você não está imprimindo os valores do imposto e do consumo. O que você faz é imprimir apenas o texto:

```
System.out.println("O imposto é ");
...
System.out.println("O Valor é de: R$ ");
```

Veja que no seu código do VisualG você imprime o valor de fato:

```
Escreva(Valor)
```

O único ajuste que você precisa fazer é adicionar a impressão do valor da variável, da mesma forma que você fez no VisualG:

```
System.out.println("O imposto é ");
System.out.println(imposto);
...
System.out.println("O Valor é de: R$ ");
System.out.println(valore);
```

Assim os valores que você calculou vão aparecer no console.